# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters - Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Now I know this question already have correct answers but I'm just trying to find why my own code wouldn't work.

Problem: Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters. Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3. My code takes too long to output and it outputs 1.

My code:

```
public class problemOne {

    static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int count, longest = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
            count = 1;
            for (int y = x + 1; y < s.length(); y++) {
                if (x != y) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    longest = Math.max(longest, count);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return longest;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcabcbb";
        System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring(str));
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: in your loop, you're now actually looking at the *characters* at all. You're only using `s` to find out its length. When do you expect `if (x != y)` to be false, given that you're starting with `y = x + 1` and increasing `y`?

Comment: Next hint: now would be a good time to learn about debugging. You've got a relatively simple program, so if you debug into it, you should be able to see where it's not behaving as you expect it to.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've been trying to find what's wrong for minutes and couldn't see it, thanks for that, I've fixed it now with .charAt(). Now, I actually found out my code is a mess and wouldn't work correctly even after fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner loop, there is: `if (x != y)`. I guess you meant to compare characters here, not numbers.

And then: how does you inner loop "know" what characters have been processed before? Maybee the inner loop is for comparing the current character with the ones already processed? But instead you compare numbers.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question. The OP didn't want a different solution - they wanted to know what was wrong with their current code.